# Discrepancies between numerical and analytical solution for particle in a finite potential well?

Tags: eigensystem, quantum-mechanics

### Analytical

Inside the box, the wavefunction is:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 \psi(x)}{dx^2} = E \psi(x) \iff
 \frac{d^2 \psi(x)}{dx^2}  = k^2 \psi(x)
\end{equation}
where $k = \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$. Outside the box:
\begin{equation}
 -\frac{\hbar^2}{m} \frac{\partial^2 \psi(x)}{\partial x^2} = (E - V_0) \psi(x) \iff \frac{\partial^2 \psi(x)}{\partial x^2} = \alpha^2 \psi(x)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2m(V_0 - E)}}{\hbar}$. The solutions for the Schrödinger equation for a particle in a finite potential well are:

\begin{equation}
 \psi(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
  Ce^{\alpha x}, \text{if } x < -\frac{L}{2}\\
  A\sin(kx) + B\cos(kx), \text{if } -\frac{L}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{L}{2}\\
  Fe^{-\alpha x} , \text{if } x > \frac{L}{2} 
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Next, $\psi(x)$ must be continuous and differentiable, which means that the value of the functions and their derivatives must match at the boundaries, $-\frac{L}{2}$ and $\frac{L}{2}$. Depending on whether the solution is symmetric, $\psi(-x) = \psi(x)$, or anti-symmetric, $\psi(-x) = -\psi(x)$, $A = 0$, $C = F$ or $B = 0$. $C = -F$, respectively. For the symmetric case:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{|l@{}}
   Fe^{-\alpha L/2} = B\cos(k L/2)\\
   -\alpha F e^{-\alpha L/2} = -\alpha B\cos(k L/2)
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

taking the ratio of the above two to give us $\alpha = k \tan(k L/2)$. Similarly, from the anti-symmetric case we get $\alpha = -k \cot(k L/2)$.Both $\alpha$ and $k$ depend on the energy, $E$, making the above equations transcendental. To solve them we make the following substitutions:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{|l@{}}
  u = \frac{L}{2} \alpha \\
  v = \frac{L}{2} k  = \frac{L}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}\quad (1)
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

Additionally, $u^2 = u_{0}^{2} - v^2$ where $u_0 = \frac{m L^{2} V_0}{2 \hbar^2}$. This leads to:

\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{u_{0}^{2} - v^2} =
 \begin{cases} 
   v \tan(v)\\
  -v \cot(v) 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

To calculate the above I use the following Octave code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

x = 0 :0.1:5;  % coordinates  interval.
L = 1;         % well width.
U_0 = 40;      % well depth.
hbar = 1;      % Planck's constant.
m = 1;         % particle mass.
u_0sq = (m*(L^2)*U_0 ) / (2 * hbar^2);

lhs = @(x) sqrt(u_0sq - x.^2);
rhs_s = @(x) x.*tan(x);
rhs_a = @(x) -x.*cot(x);

plot(x, lhs(x), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2, ...,
     x, rhs_s(x), 'b', 'LineWidth', 2, ...,
     x, rhs_a(x), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2)
xlabel('v')
axis([0 5 0 5])
```

From $(1)$ and the three intesection values<sup>1</sup> for $v$ from the below plot, the results for the energies are:

> 3.2724
>   12.8576
>   27.7294

[image]

---

### Numerical

Now, for the numerical solution I use the following:

```
% Parameters for solving problem in the interval -L < x < L.
L = 5;                                               % Interval Length.                                                                                                                                
N = 1000;                                            % No of points.
x = linspace(-L, L, N)';                             % Coordinate vector
dx = x(2) - x(1);                                    % Coordinate step

% Finite square well of width 2w and depth given by U_0.
U_0 = 40;                           w = L / 10;                                          
U = -U_0*(heaviside(x + w) - heaviside(x - w));

% Discretized (three-point finite-difference) representation of the Laplacian. 
e = ones(N, 1);                                                      
Lap = spdiags([e  -2*e e], [-1 0 1], N, N)  

% Total Hamiltonian
hbar = 1;                                                                  
m = 1;                                                                     
H = -1/2*(hbar^2 / m)*Lap + spdiags(U, 0, N, N);  % T = H + U.

% Find (first 3) (smalest algebraic) eigenvalues.
nmodes = 3;             options.disp = 0;
[V, E] = eigs(H, nmodes, 'sa' , options);            
[E, ind] = sort(diag(E));                            
E
```

The results for the energies are:

> 36.72
>   27.14
>   12.27

I'm expecting some error but in this case, the energies differ in an order of magnitude.

Clearly, I am doing something wrong but I don't know whether the error is in the analytical or numerical solution. What am I doing wrong here? Any hint will be appreciated.

---

<sub>1. The vertical lines are discontinuity points.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your potential for the numerical case is wrong. The potential should be a big positive number, so the solution tends to zero outside the well when the value of the potential increases.

If you check the solutions in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Finding_wavefunctions_for_the_bound_state) for the first three (bounded) states they should be

$$E_n = \frac{2\hbar^2 v_n^2}{m L^2}\, ,$$

with $v_1 = 1.28$, $v_2 = 2.54$ and $v_3=3.73$, or just

\begin{align}
&E_1 = 3.2768\\
&E_2 = 12.9032\\
&E_3 = 27.8258
\end{align}

Following is your code with corrections, notice that you also miss the step size of the finite difference.

```
% Parameters for solving problem in the interval -L < x < L.
L = 5;  % Interval Length.                                                                                                                                
N = 1000;  % No of points.
x = linspace(-L, L, N)';  % Coordinate vector
dx = x(2) - x(1);  % Coordinate step

% Finite square well of width 2w and depth given by U_0.
U_0 = 40;
w = L / 10;                                          
U = U_0*(1 - heaviside(x + w) + heaviside(x - w));

% Discretized (three-point finite-difference) representation of the Laplacian. 
e = ones(N, 1);                                                  
Lap = spdiags([e  -2*e e], [-1 0 1], N, N)/dx^2;

% Total Hamiltonian
hbar = 1;                                                           
m = 1;                                                    
H = -0.5*(hbar^2 / m)*Lap + spdiags(U, 0, N, N);  % T = H + U

% Find (first 3) (smalest algebraic) eigenvalues.
nmodes = 6;
options.disp = 0;
[V, E] = eigs(H, nmodes, 'sm' , options);            
[E, ind] = sort(diag(E));                            
disp(E)
```

The following is the answer given by the code

```
 3.2724
12.8576
27.7294
40.1985
40.2454
40.7874
```